# Deploy Tomcat/Docker Hello-World to Heroku returning HTTP:503

Tags: docker, heroku, tomcat9

I admit I am somewhat in the weeds w/r/t managing port configs with this little app that lives inside a Tomcat container.

I know TC listens on 8080.  I assume that, as long as whatever port Heroku comes up with is mapped to 8080 in the container, the request should reach the container at least.  I have tried to follow their instructions accordingly.  Have no idea why webapp-runner is needed but Heroku specifies it.

However, when developing locally (where it works fine), the name of the target war is specified in the request (ie http://127.0.0.1:8080/DockerJavaWebApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/).  I'm not sure how to do that, or if it's necessary, in the deployment.  And I'd rather not have to do it locally, either.

Any assistance appreciated with thanks in advance.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM tomcat
ADD target/DockerJavaWebApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run" , "-b", "0.0.0.0:$PORT"]
```

**docker-compose:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    image: yermammy #tomcat_test
    environment:
      - PORT
```

**Procfile:**

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

**heroku logs (elided):**
(does that port mapping look like it has the right syntax?)

```
2021-05-25T00:39:16.515638+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `catalina.sh run -b 0.0.0.0:\48915`

2021-05-24T18:04:27.398894+00:00 app[web.1]: 24-May-2021 18:04:27.398 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [6388] milliseconds

2021-05-24T18:05:07.025452+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=blah-tomcat-test.herokuapp.com request_id=0b87e97e-ca2f-4406-b4f2-329890f923db fwd="65.35.200.119" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2021-05-24T18:05:07.725522+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

2021-05-24T18:05:07.785462+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL

2021-05-24T18:05:08.146910+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-05-24T18:05:08.219013+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2021-05-24T18:05:10.482493+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=blah-tomcat-test.herokuapp.com request_id=d328a542-0466-4be5-9a82-1eda0cb42af4 fwd="65.35.200.119" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2021-05-24T18:05:12.259286+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=blah-tomcat-test.herokuapp.com request_id=c2172b8c-4a66-491d-9db1-86685a4f6662 fwd="65.35.200.119" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2021-05-24T18:05:27.529565+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/index.jsp" host=blah-tomcat-test.herokuapp.com request_id=38a21675-c542-46a1-8692-1672547b6f02 fwd="65.35.200.119" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2021-05-24T18:05:27.951191+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=blah-tomcat-test.herokuapp.com request_id=7cba1f7a-abdf-43c0-bba7-dd7341e4daee fwd="65.35.200.119" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

The war file runs fine when deployed via these instructions ( https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner#prerequisites ) -- which stipulate using GIT.

Check it out: https://stormy-wildwood-00412.herokuapp.com/index.jsp

However, the docker image containing the app fails to connect with the port provided by Heroku.